# Breakpoint not hitting on button click in Silverlight + WCF RIA Services

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have created a silverlight app using WCF RIA Services and Entity Data Model.

In mainPage.xaml page I have dropped a button and on click of that button certain operation is performing.I have put a breakpoint on button click event, but its not hitting the breakpoint when I am clicking the button.

Kindly help regarding the same!!!

Thanks 
Piyush

Comment: Does the code in the button click event get executed?

Comment: Please make it clear to get more result. did you put the breakpoint inside the button event or on the server side ( WCF )  ?

Comment: Do other breakpoints work or is it "no symbols were loaded for this project" message on breakpoint when program is running?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable "Silverlight" debugging in the web project.

Open the ["Properties"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983445.aspx) of the web project and goto page "Web". In the section "Debuggers" check the Checkbox "Silverlight".

Another problem could be, that your current build configuration is set to "Release". Change it to "Debug".

Comment: I think it checked by default.

Comment: Normally you will be ask once, when you start debugging the first time, if you want to enable silverlight debugging. I think it´s not set by default.

Comment: But It doesn't ask me anything, I created a new silverlight project after I read your comment. but it doesn't ask anything. I have looked for my previous project they are checked by default too. I didn't change anything in configuration.

Comment: The setting is stored in the .user file of the project. If this file doesn´t exist, Visual Studio will prompt a message if you want to enable Silverlight debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be caused by XAP file being opened (in some ZIP viewer) while building your solution. Visual Studio is quiet about not being able to replace the old XAP with new one and your breakpoints will be "out of sync".